# How can I use blingfire to cut a sentence well

Tags: nlp, sentence

When using blingfire, the sentence cannot be separated normally if there is title with person name.

`if '.+space+ [ Person Title Abbr ] + ... '` then cut the after title.

How can I cut this sentence?

For Example:

1. Original Text :

> On July 26, 2013, Michael G. Spinozzi, President of Sally Beauty Supply, notified the Company of his retirement from the Company with an anticipated effective date of November 8, 2013. Mr. Spinozzi has served as President of Sally Beauty Supply since 2006 and the Company is grateful for Mr. Spinozzis leadership and commitment to the success of the Company during his tenure as an officer of the Company.

Result:

- On July 26, 2013, Michael G. Spinozzi, President of Sally Beauty Supply, notified the Company of his retirement from the Company with an anticipated effective date of November 8, 2013.
- Mr.
- Spinozzi has served as President of Sally Beauty Supply since 2006 and the Company is grateful for Mr. Spinozzis leadership and commitment to the success of the Company during his tenure as an officer of the Company.

2. Original Text :

> The Company has promoted Claudia S. San Pedro, age 45, to Senior Vice President, Chief Financial Officer and Treasurer. Ms. Pedro served as Vice President of Investor Relations and Communications of the Company since January 2013 and as Vice President of Investor Relations from July 2010 until January 2013.

Result:

- The Company has promoted Claudia S. San Pedro, age 45, to Senior Vice President, Chief Financial Officer and Treasurer.
- Ms.
- Pedro served as Vice President of Investor Relations and Communications of the Company since January 2013 and as Vice President of Investor Relations from July 2010 until January 2013.

3. Original Text :

> The committees on which Mmes. Jensen and Wilkerson and Mr. Motley will serve have not been determined. Mmes. Jensen and Wilkerson and Mr. Motley will receive compensation for their services as non-employee directors in accordance with the Companys standard compensatory arrangement described in the Companys definitive Proxy Statement for its 2018 Annual Meeting under the caption Director Compensation filed pursuant to Regulation 14A with the Securities and Exchange Commission on March 29, 2018.

Result:

- The committees on which Mmes. Jensen and Wilkerson and Mr. Motley will serve have not been determined.
- Mmes.
- Jensen and Wilkerson and Mr. Motley will receive compensation for their services as non-employee directors in accordance with the Companys standard compensatory arrangement described in the Companys definitive Proxy Statement for its 2018 Annual Meeting under the caption Director Compensation filed pursuant to Regulation 14A with the Securities and Exchange Commission on March 29, 2018.